# Can i play <audio> in html, from middle without downloading complete file

Tags: html, web, html5-audio

I need to play large audio file starting at different parts. But it starts to load completely anyway.

tried to `#t=01:00:00`, `audio.currentTime` , set many headers for partial content like "Content-Range"

Is this generally possible or do I need to use third-party libraries like howler js?

Comment: HLS and MPG-DASH live streaming delivers in playable chunks.